# How can I log out from Microsoft Office apps installed on machine which I dont have access to

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, onedrive

I had a client laptop. I was logged into the microsoft account in the office apps (Word, Excel etc) installed on that laptop. Now I have left that project and am no more able to login to that laptop. Is there any way to ensure that my logins from those apps are signed out by say login to some office portal? (For example, similar to how stackexchange have checkbox to log out from all devices on [this](https://superuser.com/users/logout) page)

Comment: You mean like this [Kill the session to block access to all Office 365 resources](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudyhappypeople/2017/10/05/killing-sessions-to-a-compromised-office-365-account/#targetText=Expand%20OneDrive%20Settings%2C%20go%20to,the%20user%20to%20sign%20in.)?

Comment: Steps specified there are for office365 and sharepoint users right? I am having normal microsoft account, the one with which you can login to outlook.com or onedrive.com. So I guess those steps dont apply to me, right?